# How do I show the filename instead of the file I drag into an Emacs buffer?

Tags: drag-and-drop

I would like to drag and drop an image file into an emacs buffer and make the filename appear instead of the image. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```el
(setq dnd-protocol-alist '(("^file:" . dnd-insert-filename)))

(defun dnd-insert-filename (uri _action)
  (insert (dnd-get-local-file-name uri)))
```

I learnt the `dnd-protocol-alist` user option from Elisp manual: [(elisp) Drag and Drop](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Drag-and-Drop.html) and read its docstring to know how to customize its value.